# Change colour of raisedbutton?

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I have tried to change the colour of a `RaisedButton` using `button.tintColour = MaterialColor.blue.lighten2` but that doesn't result in a change of the button.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tintColor` on a `UIButton` by default only changes the color of the text. Try setting its `backgroundColor`

Comment: Thanks - that worked.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.